# BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans

Tags: spring-security, spring-3

I'm trying to add spring security to a regular JSF application. After repeated tries and I'm failing with the following error on tomcat bring-up.

Here is the entire stack trace. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** upon further tests, I notice the following stack trace, before the second set of SEVERE exception about BeanFactory not initialized or already closed

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderList
ener
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/
core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment;
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:87)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicat
ionContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:46
7)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

After this error, the mojarra 2.1.4 is initialized before the BeanFactory exception shows up

SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:171)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1048)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1022)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:556)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4245)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4886)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4750)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

my web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
         /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
         /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
       </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.debugDOMUpdate</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.concurrentDOMViews</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.synchronousUpdate</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Faces Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <!-- <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> -->
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.CompatResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
<!-- Extension Mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/icefaces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
    <session-timeout>90</session-timeout>
    </session-config>


    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And my applicationContext-security.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<!--  key configuration here is an entry point to be used by security intercepts -->
<http realm="Sample Realm" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" auto-config="false">

    <custom-filter ref="sessionManagementFilter" before="SESSION_MANAGEMENT_FILTER" />
    <!-- any role that is used to protect a directory, can be multiples -->
    <intercept-url pattern='/secure/**' access='ROLE_READER' />

    <!-- enable form login to use UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter [/j_spring_security_check] -->
    <form-login login-page="/general/logins/htmlLogin.faces"  
                    authentication-failure-url="/general/logins/loginFailed.jsf"/>

    <!-- logout page uses the default LogoutFilter, no changes are needed as IT accepts a GET call... -->
    <!-- here is an example logout link:
    <a href="#{request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout">Logout</a> -->
        <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
                logout-success-url="/general/main.jsf"
                invalidate-session="true"/>
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/general/logins/login.jsf" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- test with this before you hook up your LDAP or other Authentication Manager -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="joe.blow@gr.am" password="pass1234" authorities="ROLE_READER"/>
                <user name="tester@gr.com" password="pass5678" authorities="ROLE_READER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="sessionManagementFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="securityContextRepository" ref="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" />
        <beans:property name="invalidSessionUrl" value="/general/logins/sessionExpired.jsf" />
        <!-- this permits redirection to session timeout page from javascript/ajax or http -->
        <beans:property name="redirectStrategy" ref="jsfRedirectStrategy" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jsfRedirectStrategy" class="com.palm.safe.spring.security.JsfRedirectStrategy"/>
    <beans:bean id="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository"/>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Please use the formatter when you paste the stacktrace.

Comment: Did you get an appropriate answer for this question? You haven't accepted any answer here.

Comment: Hi Lambeau - Did you ever find the final answer to this problem?

Answer (score 12):

I see this code in `applicationContext-security.xml`:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
```

You might be using incorrect spring version. For example, if you are using spring-xxx (spring-security-web.jar or spring-security-core.jar) version 3.1.xx in your library, this error will come out. Try change the code in `applicationContext-security.xml` from **3.0.xsd** to **3.1.xsd** (the version number in the code must match back to the version sit in the library folder).

Hope this help.

Comment: this didn't help me... the change of xsd version didn't change the error

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `RequestContextListener` to your `web.xml` what it does is namely bind the HTTP request object to the Thread that is servicing that request. This makes beans which are request- and session-scoped available further down the call chain.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: that was informative, and I did try with the RequestContextListener added to my web.xml. Doesn't seem to change the error.

Comment: however, I updated my stack trace, I notice appContext related NoSuchMethodError, Ive updated the problem statement with it. Does that hint at anything obvious?

EVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderList
ener
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/
core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment;

Comment: I think you missed spring-context-support dependency. Add that and see

Comment: Check your spring version. if spring.jar is version 2.x, make sure other spring-xxx component (like spring-security-web or spring-security-core) are not 3.x. There are some compatibility issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and it turned out there's an issue with the maven spring dependency chain. Dependency org.springframework spring-context was imported with version 3.0.5, whereas the overall spring version I was using was 3.2.2. Explicitly adding the dependency in my pom.xml solved it.

I detected the issue by using the -verbose:class jvm argument when running the server, and checking the jars classes in the XmlWebApplicationContext inheritance tree were loaded from.

Comment: Exactly, and the same issue can happen when you are missing the security jars! I was facing the same issue and reason happened to be the missing jar files.

Answer (score 4):

While removing the comments from a particular block in applicationcontext.xml, I missed out to remove  **-->** "The end of comment". I didn't notice it and was as getting this error.

Later removed it and all was working fine!!

Answer (score 2):

I had this error as well, and the problem turned out that, with cut and paste, I had inadvertently listed the same bean twice in my spring-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="pathInfoHelper" class="org.nationalhistory.util.PathInfoHelper">
</bean>

<bean id="imageIndexer" class="org.nationalhistory.util.ImageIndexer"/>

<bean id="pathInfoHelper" class="org.nationalhistory.util.PathInfoHelper">
</bean>
```

I looked here and found this with the help of om39a's answer above (thanks!).  I had just edited the file, and knew there was a chance I had pasted something extra (or something less) inadvertently.  This double-entry, however, was NOT the bean that the error referred to!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue until I removed the project in question from the server's deployments (in JBoss Dev Studio, right-click the server and "Remove" the project in the Servers view), then did the following:

1. Restarted the JBoss EAP 6.1 server without any projects deployed.
2. Once the server had started, I then added the project in question to the server.

After this, just restart the server (in debug or run mode) by selecting the server, NOT the project itself.

This seemed to flush any previous settings/states/memory/whatever that was causing the issue, and I no longer got the error.

Answer (score 0):

use this dependecy in your pom.xml

`<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>`